# convert String to Date in android

Tags: android, date, format

anyone know how to convert the following string to Date?

"Fri Jul 30 16:19:36 GMT+02.00 2021"

i tried:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
try {String temp = value2[i].trim();
     expiry = formatter.parse(temp);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but,it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

`z` expects the format `GMT+02:00` not `GMT+02.00` replace the `.` and it should work.

Worked for me with the following code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    try {
        String temp = "Fri Jul 30 16:19:36 GMT+02:00 2021";
        Date expiry = formatter.parse(temp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: will,,after i replace,,the string is "Fri Jul 30 16:19:36 GMT+02:00 2021",,but the parse gives the error:  "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Fri Jul 30 16:19:36 GMT+02:00 2021"

Comment: It is parsed well in my side, I'll post the code, so you might see some difference

Comment: i solve the problem in this way: first,,replace "." to ":" as u indicated before;   secondly, change the constructor in this way: "SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy",Locale.US);",,,,then it works,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

`Date cDate = new Date(String);`

`String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cDate);`